# How to get pipenv to work in multiple versions of brew python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I have multiple versions of python on my mac using brew. I switch between them using brew switch python .

> Usage: brew switch   python installed versions:
>   3.6.4_4, 3.7.0, 3.7.4

Some projects i am working on have been created using pipenv. I have installed pipenv on my default version of python3 `3.7.4`. It works fine.

There are some projects where i need to switch to python version 3.6.4_4. Using brew switch python 3.6.4_4.

However when i try to use pipenv in 3.6 i get the following error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/removed_name/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/bin/python3.7
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

How can i get pipenv to play nice in both 3.6 and 3.7

I have tried:

uninstall pipenv and reinstall it when im in 3.6, but it will install 3.7 version.

Comment: how do you install it ? Every Python should have own `pip` to install own modules - ie. on Linux I have `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.6`, `pip3.7` - or you can use python to install module `python3.6 -m pip install ...`

Comment: brew install pipenv